# Return a new array with specified values?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to write the following function code

```
int* returnFilledArray() {
 int* arr = new int[2];
 arr[0] = 1;
 arr[1] = 2;
 return arr;
}
```

somehow like that? (create and fill the array as one liner).

```
int* returnFilledArray() {
 return new int {1,2};
}
```

if have tried various combinations, but I allways get some syntax errors, so when if it's 
possible I would be thankful for a detailed explanation.

Comment: try this int[] returnFilledArray{......}

Comment: Be aware that if you create and return an array like that, there is no way to know how long it actually is, unless you have a known constant length for all arrays. I'd much rather recommend `std::vector` instead of a plain array.

Comment: @Mephane: `std::vector` also has the advantage that you could use [Boost.Assign](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/assign/doc/index.html) (only needed pre-C++11).

Comment: @moon: `int[] returnFilledArray();` and `int* returnFilledArray()` are exactly the same function signature, so that comment (while upvoted) makes no sense at all.

Comment: I can't use std::vector because we have to code a small compiler without using datastructures from the std.

Comment: why it has to be a one liner?

Comment: @Nicoretti: Then about about a plain old C-like `struct int_array { int* data, int length };` and returning such a struct by value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you are trying to do in Standard C++ (03) without using special libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Yes..

```
std::vector<int> returnFilledArray()
{
  int a[] = {1, 2};
  return std::vector<int>(a, a+2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ 0x supports [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Initializer_lists) - is that an option for you?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is possible because you can do something like that in Java. I do not need it necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

I had answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643923/c-initializing-non-static-member-array/5644008#5644008). You can use following technique:

```
template<typename T, T _0, T _1, T _2, T _3, T _4> struct Array
{
  static T* Init (T *a)
  {
    a[0] = _0;
    a[1] = _1;
    a[2] = _2;
    a[3] = _3;
    a[4] = _4;
    return a;
  }
};

int* fun ()
{
  return Array<int, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>::Init(new int[5]);
}
```

Comment: this is just an example for 5 elements; you can change the number of elements as per your need. Here the example is for `int`, but the same struct you can use for any type.

Comment: So a simple version like in java:

public static int[] myFunc() {
  return new int[] {2,3,4,19};
}

is in c++ not possible?

Comment: Not in current standarad, in C++0x the same feature as Java is introduced called "Initializer lists" where you can declare such arrays. Additionally, you can initialize variables when you declare them in `class' itself.

Answer (score 0):

In `C++0x`:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> returnFilledArray()
{
  return std::vector<int> {1,2} ;
}
```

Comment: He said he can't use a vector

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to use `std::vector`, then you can try a macro:

```
#define FILLED_ARRAY(name) int name[] = {1, 2}
```

Comment: -1:  he wants a dynamically allocated array.  this one is automatic, and will fall off the stack.

Comment: i wasn't sure if he REALLY wants the array to be on heap. or just wants a one liner.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm not sure either, so I edited your post and reversed the d/v

Comment: @John, thank you. but what is the edit!? i don't see any change.

Comment: All I did was add a space at the end.  I couldn't reverse my d/v because it had been there for 15 minutes.  So I just edited it myself with an empty edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do similar task using

```
int *ptr = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
```

you can then return from your function as

```
return (new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```