# Initializing member array in constructor initialization list (before C++11)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, coding-style, initialization-list

As far as I know, before C++11, the only way to initialize a member array in a constructor initialization list was to do, e.g., the following:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int arg) : member(arg), memberArray() {
    // anything else that needs to be done in the c'tor
}
```

However, I have had several people tell me they frown on this method, and that it would possibly be safer/more readable to zero-initialize it in a `for` loop in the body of the constructor.

I don't have C++11 support available yet, so I can't use an initializer list, etc. Are there any guidelines anyone has heard of that discourage initializing member arrays in the constructor initializer list?

Also, testing indicates no, but there shouldn't be any problem using this syntax for a multi-dimensional array, correct? (E.g., this isn't some part of the standard that certain compilers screw up for some reason...)

I don't mean for this to be a subjective question - I'm simply interested to know if there is a good reason to use/not to use the above syntax.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing a member array in constructor initializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057948/initializing-a-member-array-in-constructor-initializer)

Comment: No that isn't the only way, `MyClass::MyClass(int arg) : member(arg), memberArray(some_function(arg))`, where `some_function` constructs the value you want, works perfectly well.

Comment: So, in the case of a 2-dimensional array of `int`s of dimension `[][3]`, `some_function` would return a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s? Thanks for the tip, that's great to know.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I did see that question, but I am more interested in whether this is good practice than how to go about it exactly.

Comment: In C++03, you simply *cannot* initialize member arrays (except for value-initialization).

Comment: @KerrekSB Does the above syntax not work then? I thought it zero-initialized the member array, no?

Comment: @llakais: That's what value-initialization is.

Comment: @llakais: Yes, it does - that's *value-initialization*. But you can't initialize arrays to any *other* values. If all you need is zero, then you're fine.

Comment: @llakais That's right. some_function can be defined globally, or it can be a static member of your class, but it cannot be a member function since you haven't constructed your object yet.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, got it. Thanks for your patience explaining that!

Comment: Note that some compilers will warn if only some members are initialized in an initializer list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to take a look as this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5644911/1280582) on StackOverflow : using static functions to initialize your member arrays in initialization list can achieve what you are looking for :

```
class MyClass
{
   typedef std::array< int, 2 > t_myA;
   static t_myA fillFunction(){ static t_myA const ret = {1,2}; return ret; };

   t_myA myArray;

   public MyClass();
}

MyClass::MyClass()
 : myArray( fillFunction() )
{
}
```